# Guava Hasher some times give diff result for same object

Tags: java, guava

I need create a hash code from Map with Key(Custom Object) and Value As Set of custom object, i Use Guava 18.0

```
@Getter
   public final class StockKey {

    @ValidIsin
    private final String isin;

    @ValidExchangeId
    private final Integer exchangeId;

    @ValidCurrency
    private final String currency
   }


   @EqualsAndHashCode
    public final class ClientAssetPosition {

    public static final double EPSILON = 0.0001;

    @NotNull
    private final PositionType type;

    @NotNull
    private final Double quantity;

    @Nullable
    @Getter
    private Double coveredOptions;

    @Nullable
    @Getter
    private Double blockedCoveringUnderlyings;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Boolean excluded;
    }
```

So i have a function that create   HashCode

```
 public static HashCode getHashCodeWithSha256(Map<StockKey, Set<ClientAssetPosition>> positions) {
        final Hasher hasher = Hashing.sha256().newHasher();
        for (Map.Entry<StockKey, Set<ClientAssetPosition>> positionsEntry : positions.entrySet()) {
            hasher.putObject(positionsEntry.getKey(), STOCK_KEY_FUNNEL);
            for (ClientAssetPosition asset : positionsEntry.getValue()) {
                hasher.putObject(asset, CLIENT_ASSET_POSITION_FUNNEL);
            }
        }
        return hasher.hash();
    }
```

I use such Funnel

```
public static final Funnel<StockKey> STOCK_KEY_FUNNEL = new Funnel<StockKey>() {
    @Override
    public void funnel(StockKey from, PrimitiveSink into) {
        into.putString(from.getIsin()).putString(from.getCurrency()).putInt(from.getExchangeId());
    }
};
public static final Funnel<ClientAssetPosition> CLIENT_ASSET_POSITION_FUNNEL = new Funnel<ClientAssetPosition>() {
    @Override
    public void funnel(ClientAssetPosition from, PrimitiveSink into) {
        into.putDouble(from.getQuantity()).putString(from.getType().name());
    }
};
```

and for same Map this function some time's return different HashCode
I find it with this unit test. This test failed if run it from maven, but not every time.

```
@Test
    public void testSamePortfolioSameHAshCodeOrdersASC(){
        Map<StockKey, Set<ClientAssetPosition>> positions = new HashMap<>();
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS_FEB_12_17_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_12_5_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_M10));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_12_5_P, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_13_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAY12_13_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_M10));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_13_P, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS_JAN_12_17_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS_JAN_12_17_P, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSH_APR12, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSH_MAR12, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positions.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSH_MAY12, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));

        Map<StockKey, Set<ClientAssetPosition>> positionsv2 = new HashMap<>();
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_12_5_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_M10));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_12_5_P, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSH_APR12, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAY12_13_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_M10));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_13_P, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS_JAN_12_17_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS_JAN_12_17_P, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBS_FEB_12_17_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSH_MAR12, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSN_MAR12_13_C, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101, PredefinedAssetPosition.OWN_1));
        positionsv2.put(PredefinedStockKeys.UBSH_MAY12, Sets.newHashSet(PredefinedAssetPosition.C_ORD_M1, PredefinedAssetPosition.ORD_B101));
        HashCode hashCodeWithSha256Expected = HashHelper.getHashCodeWithSha256(positions);
        HashCode hashCodeWithSha256Exist = HashHelper.getHashCodeWithSha256(positionsv2);
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(hashCodeWithSha256Expected.asBytes(), hashCodeWithSha256Exist.asBytes());
    }
```

Can some one explain me what i do wrong?

Comment: Just one thing... You use Guava, so why don't you use a `Multimap`?

Comment: Other than that, wild guess: ordering! Remember that nothing guarantees that the ordering of keys/values of a `HashMap`, nor values of a `HashSet`, are guaranteed at all. I believe this is the problem here.

Comment: This part of code really old, and rewrite domain object that contain this map is too expensive. We don't have time for it.

Comment: Yes order is possible i'am also think about it. i try to make such improovments   Collections.sort(positions.entrySet()) which do not help

Comment: That's not the only problem you have. Your sets also need to be ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with ordering. Even from one invocation to another, if you put the same key/value pair or value in a `HashMap` or `HashSet` respectively, there is no guarantee whatsoever that the ordering of entries will remain the same between two invocations. Much less so across JVM runs, of course.

You therefore need to rewrite your hash calculating method so that it enforce an order before calculating the hash...

Which, since you use Guava, is easy: use `Ordering.sortedCopy()`.

This should do it; however, please do note that this supposes that your `StockKey` and `ClientAssetPosition` classes implement `Comparable`:

```
public static HashCode getHashCodeWithSha256(Map<StockKey, Set<ClientAssetPosition>> positions) 
{
    final Hasher hasher = Hashing.sha256().newHasher();

    final Iterable<StockKey> orderedKeys
        = Ordering.sortedCopy(positions.keySet());

    Iterable<ClientAssetPosition> orderedAssets;

    for (final StockKey key: orderedKeys) {
        hasher.putObject(key, STOCK_KEY_FUNNEL);

        orderedAssets = Ordering.sortedCopy(positions.get(key));

        for (final ClientAssetPosition asset: orderedAssets)
            hasher.putObject(asset, CLIENT_ASSET_POSITION_FUNNEL);
    }
    return hasher.hash();
}
```

---

**HOWEVER**: really consider switching to a `Multimap`. And recall that it also has a `.asMap()` method if you need backwards compatibility at some point.

Comment: So easy...

I even start dig, inside jvm to find any differ between hach creation on my jenkins machine and local. because on local it's always work.

Comment: Hmwell, of course, this also requires that your keys and values do implement `Comparable`. Otherwise you'll need to write one...

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Hasher documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hasher.html#hash()), you will find out :

> Warning: Chunks of data that are put into the Hasher are not
>   delimited. The resulting HashCode is dependent only on the bytes
>   inserted, and the order in which they were inserted...

As order matter, hashmaps with different key/value order produces different hashes.

You may solve this by using an ordered/sorted structure or hash pre-processing in getHashCodeWithSha256.